# robocopy /mir problem

Tags: backup, mirroring, robocopy

i am using robocopy to take backup from one folder with following syntax

```
      robocopy "source" "destination" /mir
```

but the issue i am facing is
if file is in destination but not in source, its deleted automatically from destination
but i dont need this,

i need only copy from source to destination....

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to copy from point a to point b, you don't need to use `/mir` at all.

Comment: Instead add /s or /e to copy subfolders.

Answer (score 2):

/MIR will process deletes and make your destination look exactly like the source. If you want to just copy new files and not care about having a matching destination, just use Robocopy /E